# Отобразить favicon

Tags: php

Необходимо отобразить favicon рядом с линками на сайте, как в [поисковой выдаче яндекса](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=rambler&lr=213). Например:

```
<div>Фавиконка</div><div><a href="#">Ссылка на сайт</a></div>
```

У меня нет ни малейших идей как это сделать. Кто-то может помочь??

P.S. Линки генерируются динамически из базы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, линк на favicon [лежит в теге](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization) `<link rel="shortcut icon" ...` из `<head>`. (См. ответ [[@ROOT](/users/4208/root)](/users/4208/root).)

Если там такого нету, можно [проверить существование](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#History) yoursite.com/favicon.ico.

Это всё наверное лучше всего сделать на стороне сервера. Для этого придётся (попробовать) загрузить страничку с сайта и распарсить её (но вы же всё равно это делаете, если у вас поиск, правда?).

Comment: Нет у меня поиска(( Парсинг страниц не выполняется, да и не нужен. Есть база из которой извлекаются линки вида `http://www.example.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&tbo=d`. Максимум что я могу сделать, с помощью `parse_url` получить `http://www.example.ru/favicon.ico`, но вот беда: фавиконки не всегда лежат там. Яндекс же отображает фавиконки где бы они не лежали. Вот это мне собственно и нужно.

Comment: @co11ter: а Яндекс честно загружает и парсит страницу, как же без этого? И вам так надо. Тем более, вам ведь не надо разобрать _всю_ страницу, только `<head>`.

Answer (score 2):

Мне когда-то тоже нужно было получать favicon с других сайтов. Открыл для себя вот такую ссылку http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=здесь_адрес_сайта

Вашем случае должно быть что-то вроде

```
<div><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=здесь_адрес_сайта" \></div><div><a href="#">Ссылка на сайт</a></div>
```

Comment: Завтра попробую

Comment: Увы работает не со всеми URL. с яндекса тянет хорошо в URL обязательно указывать протокол.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

для `<head/>`. Не поможет?

Comment: Нет. Я знаю, что таким способом подключается favicon. В свойстве `href` может лежать любой путь, правильно? Мне нужно не выполняя сложного парсинга страниц (как предлагает @VladD) получить путь к фавиконке. Возможно?

Comment: > В свойстве href может лежать любой путь, правильно?

Да.

> Мне нужно не выполняя сложного парсинга страниц (как предлагает @VladD) получить путь к фавиконке. Возможно?

Нет. Потому что фавиконка **нигде больше не прописывается**, кроме как в `<head></head>` на странице. Поэтому, чтобы извлечь этот путь вам придётся парсить страницу.

Есть [попытка стандартизировать передачу иконок (и других параметров) через http-заголовки](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html), но это пока только проект.